# How to optimize update of object array in useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I have a data structure that is like this:

```
    const dataObj = {
    myparam: 'Hello', 
    data: [
      {
        id: 1, checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2, checked: true
      }
    
      {
        id: 3, checked: false
      }
    ]
   }
```

I have been experimenting with `useReducer` since I wanted to update my arrayList so that when I send in my payload I could change the object with id 1 to be checked/unchecked.

I solved this by doing this:

```
const reducer = (state: StateType, action: Action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  let newArrayChecked: Array<DataItems> = [];
  let newArrayUnchecked: Array<DataItems> = [];
  switch (type) {
    case ActionKind.Checked:
      newArrayChecked = state.items.map((item) => {
        const it = item;

        if (item.id === payload.id) it.checked = true;

        return it;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        items: newArrayChecked,
      };

    case ActionKind.UnChecked:
      newArrayUnchecked = state.items.map((item) => {
        const it = item;

        if (item.id === payload.id) it.checked = false;

        return it;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        items: newArrayUnchecked,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Im not so happy about this since for starters its repetative code more or less and looks ugly.
Im wondering if there is a better way to do this with useReducer? Im fairly new to this Hook and looking for code optimazation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just update like this:

```
case ActionKind.Checked:
  newArrayChecked = state.items.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      checked: item.id === payload.id ? true: item.checked
    };
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    items: newArrayChecked,
  };

case ActionKind.UnChecked:
  newArrayChecked = state.items.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      checked: iitem.id === payload.id ? false : item.checked
    };
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    items: newArrayUnchecked,
  };
```